If $\sum_{i=0}^{n}e^{\lambda_{i}\cdot t}\cdot q_{i}(t) = 0$ then $q_{i}(t) = 0$ where $q_{i}(t)$ is complex polynomial with real variable $t$.
So I have that question

Fix a finite set of pairwise distinct complex numbers $\{\lambda_{i}\}$ and some natural numbers $\{p_{i}\}$
Prove: the functions $\{t^{j}\cdot e^{\lambda_{i}\cdot t}\}_{\stackrel{0\leq i \leq n}{0 \leq j \leq p_{i}}}$ are $\mathbb{C}$ - linearly independent

So here is my attempt:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{p_{i}}C_{i,j}t^{j}\cdot e^{\lambda_{i}\cdot t}\equiv0$$
and get to:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}e^{\lambda_{i}\cdot t}\cdot\left(\sum_{j=0}^{p_{i}}C_{i,j}t^{j}\right)=0$$
denote : $q_{i}(t)=\sum_{j=0}^{p_{i}}C_{i,j}t^{j}$ we get that if we'll prove that:
$\sum_{i=0}^{n}e^{\lambda_{i}\cdot t}\cdot q_{i}(t)=0$ implies that $q_i(t)=0$ for all $0\leq i \leq n$ we'll finish, but I can't figure out how to show that, I know how to show that $\{e^{\lambda_i \cdot t}\}_{i=0}^{n}$ is $\mathbb{C}$ - linearly independent if $\lambda_i \neq \lambda_j$ for all $i \neq j$ and know how to show that if $q_i(t)=0$ then $C_{i,j}=0$ for all $j$ (both proved by Vandermonde matrix)

I've seen some questions here related to that but not exactly that, the questions I've seen talked about the last two lines I've said in the last paragraph
I'll glad for some help with that, thank you in advance.

Have you tried inducting on the number of $\lambda_i$?  (For induction the varying $p_i$ is a distraction so I'd suggest homogenizing the indices to be $\sum_{j=0}^M$ for some fixed $M$).  I wonder why does your title say $t\in \mathbb R$?  It seems nicer to do this for $t\in \mathbb C$ and this should get you to the same place since (non-constant, single variable) analytic functions have isolated zeros.

@user8675309
I've tried it and I've tried to divide by $e^{-\max{\text{Re}(\lambda_1),\text{Re}(\lambda_2)}}$ and let $t \to \infty$ but I can't see what to do if $\text{Re}(\lambda_1) = \text{Re}(\lambda_2)$, and because of it I can't see how to do that by induction.
About the real variable $t$ it's because we can't use any heavy result from complex analysis theory.

The induction I had in mind was to attack say $q_n(t)$ by multiplying by $\exp\big( -\lambda_n \cdot t\big)$ and start taking derivatives -- polynomials are nilpotent in this respect but other analytic functions are not; after killing $q_n(t)$ you can call on an induction hypothesis.  But I'm loathe to write up a solution only to find out rudimentary complex analyisis is disallowed.   It isn't even clear to me what $\exp\big(\lambda_i \cdot t\big)$ means if you haven't studied complex analysis or what it means to take a derivative of such a thing.

@user8675309
Oh, I see what you're aiming for, but after writing it down, I see that differentiation $\deg(q_{n}(t))+1$ times get you another polynomial that equal to zero (you can deduce immediately that the leading coefficient is zero, but maybe there some cancellation in the other terms).
I specifically have learnt complex analysis, but some other who take the course with me aren't, and we don't should rely on complex analysis (maybe only what is $e^{it}$ but nothing more).

You're close.  If the "leading coefficient" was zero to begin with, then it wasn't really the leading coefficient.  So the problem collapses to the the rather trivial Base Case of $\exp\big(\lambda \cdot t\big)\cdot p(t)$ is identically zero.

It's seems like induction within induction, because for all $i$ we get $C_{i,p_i} = 0$, and we used only that it's the "leading coefficient" so from the same argument $C_{i,p_{i}-1}=0$ and so on, I suppose we can take some minimal index in the first place which solve that problem, I think that from here I know how to proceed.
Thank you very much !
